# Calling a js function from another content script file

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, google-calendar-api, getscript

I have a file a.js that is related to the a.html file.
Then. I have another content-script file, that modifies calendar.google.com
I added a button on the calendar page, and when I press it, I want to call a function from the other file:
I have done this. but I get an 404 error for it:

```
  $.getScript("vidyoChromeExt.js", function(){

                           alert("Script loaded but not necessarily executed.");
                            reLogin("event");

                        });
```

The issue is that it searches for the file inside:

```
jquery-2.0.3.min.js:6 GET https://calendar.google.com/calendar/vidyoChromeExt.js?_=1465892174555 404 ()
```

so instead of taking the root from my extension, it takes the root from the calendar.google.com page, so it won't find my file. How can I make it point to the files from my project?

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute path to the js file?
$.getScript(" h t t p://example.com/vidyoChromeExt.js", function(){..});

Comment: It's a chrome extension. Is it possible to get a absolute path of it? It's installed in chrome, it's not on the internet. So bassically that's my issue. I don't know how to get the absolute path from a extension file

Comment: [chrome.runtime.getURL](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getURL); for example: `$.getScript(chrome.runtime.getURL("vidyoChromeExt.js", function(){ ...`

Comment: Thanks, will test and let you know now

Comment: I get this back:

    jquery-2.0.3.min.js:6Denying load of chrome-extension://oikblolpjbafignnpogigckankmckpie/vidyoChromeExt.js?_=1465894628315. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.

Comment: The error says what you should do. See [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) or search for code on google/stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `chrome.runtime.getURL("vidyoChromeExt.js")`.

You have to include the file in the web_accessible_resources section of manifest file:

`"web_accessible_resources": ["vidyoChromeExt.js"]`